# Matplotlib - Advanced event picking

Tags: python, events, matplotlib

I am currently playing around with a small interactive **matplotlib** script that I want to use to mark different events within an image.

In order to make it more flexible I want to create it in a way that I can pick events either per mouse-click (and somewhat vary the brush-size of my curser, i.e. the number of adjacent points that are co-selected) *or* within a polygon.

So far, I managed to implement changing the *brush-size* for events that I select with left-click and drawing a polyline into my plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook


points = []
bs = 5 #brush size


def onclick(event):
    global points
    points.append([event.xdata, event.ydata])

    if bs == 1:
        ax.plot(event.xdata+bs, event.ydata+bs,'b+')
    elif bs == 3:
        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata+1,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata-1,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata+1, event.ydata,'b+')
    ax.plot(event.xdata-1, event.ydata,'b+')
    ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata,'b+')
    elif bs == 5:
        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata+1,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata-1,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata+1, event.ydata,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata-1, event.ydata,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata+2,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata-2,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata+2, event.ydata,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata-2, event.ydata,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata+1, event.ydata+1,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata-1, event.ydata-1,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata+1, event.ydata-1,'b+')
        ax.plot(event.xdata-1, event.ydata+1,'b+')



    plt.draw()


class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):

        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',self)
        #self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self)


    def __call__(self, event):
        #print('click', event)
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()
        return self



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title(('click to build line segments. brush size %d; press button to paint') % bs)
line, = ax.plot(points, 'r+--')
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onclick)

ax.set_xlim((0, 10))
ax.set_ylim((0, 10))
plt.show()
```

1. Is there a way in **matplotlib** to switch between the lists where the X/Y coordinates of the individual picks are stored by pressing a hotkey?
2. Does **matlablib** support autopicking of events which lie within my polyline?
3. Can I delete picked events either by something equivalent to *CTRL-Z* or an eraser?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to all three points is surely positive but it is not so clear what actual problem you have. (1) Depending on the key that is pressed, use a different list to append the values to. (2) Not clear what "autopicking" means, but using a pick_event you may easily obtain all points from the same line that was picked. (3) would require to be able to identify the point that was picked within the list and remove it from it. That is sure possible. At the end I don't see any problem, it's just some work to implement all of it. Not sure if you can expect anyone actually doing that work for you.

Comment: I do not expect anyone to do the work for me but maybe a reference or pseudo code - what would be the fun of programming in this case?;) By autopicking I mean auto-selecting x/y coordinates within a drawn polygon. what I figured out is the utilisation of *widgets* which allows me to switch between lists though